# Need to Iterate through ListBox to pull records with True Values from Boolean Fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a (poorly designed) db that contains a table of Volunteers. Within this table are 70+ Yes/No fields. Each field represents a County that each Volunteer could elect to serve. Each Volunteer could select *multiple* Counties.

I have a report that must allow selection of multiple Counties. That list must then be compared to the Boolean fields selection by selection, retaining records with only True values.

If you check some of my recent questions, I've had similar problems, but the difference was *displaying* boolean selections as text on the report. Only just now discovered selection criteria code isn't doing what I thought ... Here's what's been done so far:

```
Dim s As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
Dim t As TCondition   'this is to compile multiple variables into one large "where" clause to run the report. 3 such variables are coded in this function.
Set ctl = Me.Counties
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
   If t.WhereCondition = "" Then
     For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
        t.WhereCondition = (ctl.ItemData(s) & " = -1")
          Next s
Else
     For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
       t.WhereCondition = t.WhereCondition & " AND (ctl.ItemData(s) = -1)"
          Next s
  End If
End If
```

Where this broke on me was if someone selected more than one County. I realized they were only getting the last County selected.

For Example - Counties: red, blue, silver, and green would only return Green.

A similar issue had come up with Volunteer Positions. I needed to account for selecting *multiple*

So I found the following:

```
Public Function listBoxToString(ByRef theListBox As ListBox, Optional ByVal theDelimiter As String = vbNullString)
  Dim varTemp As Variant

  listBoxToString = vbNullString

  For Each varTemp In theListBox.ItemsSelected
    If listBoxToString <> vbNullString Then listBoxToString = listBoxToString & ","
    listBoxToString = listBoxToString & theDelimiter & theListBox.ItemData(varTemp) & theDelimiter
  Next varTemp
End Function
```

This takes all selections of a ListBox and makes a comma separated list of them. This WORKED for the Positions fields (there are multiple) because those field values are TEXT.

I tried to apply that to Counties as follows:

```
Dim s As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim t As TCondition 
Set ctl = Me.Counties
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
s = listBoxToString(Me.Counties, Chr(34))
   If t.WhereCondition = "" Then
        t.WhereCondition = (ctl.ItemData(s) & " = -1")
Else
       t.WhereCondition = t.WhereCondition & " AND (ctl.ItemData(s) = -1)"
  End If
End If
```

It does NOT work for Counties, because ListBox returns TEXT that must then be compared to values in County that are BOOLEAN. So, logically, I get Data Type Mismatch error.

I have a separate piece of code, used to help *display* the Counties list on the report. It pulls records at runtime, takes the ID of the record, zeroes in on the Indexes of the Boolean fields, and converts them to the Name of the fields:

```
Public Function MakeListCounties(intID As Integer) As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strList As String
Dim x As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Volunteer WHERE ID=" & intID)
For x = 44 To 105
    If rs(x).Type = dbBoolean Then
        If rs(x) = True Then strList = strList & rs(x).Name & ", "
    End If
Next
If strList <> "" Then MakeListCounties = Left(strList, (Len(strList) - 2))
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Is there a way to work with this to get what I want? This may be superfluous, and, if so, apologies, and completely ignore that part.

To recap - I need to iterate through a ListBox of values, compare them with values of 70+ Boolean fields, retaining only records where Boolean = True for field names matching value(s) in the ListBox

Comment: Don't normally like dynamic parameters in query but this might need one. Think I would call function from query. Function returns True or False. Criteria under the constructed field would be `=True`.

Comment: I'm very beginner at OOP. I know how to call a function in Query design, but, it's the creating of the function that does this that has me at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first code snippet to the following. The reason you were always getting the last county is because your loop was overwriting the previous WHERE clause values.

```
Dim s As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
Dim t As TCondition
Set ctl = Me.Counties
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each s In ctl.ItemsSelected
        t.WhereCondition = t.whereCondition & ctl.ItemData(s) & " = -1 OR"
    Next s
    ' trim trailing " OR"
    t.WhereCondition = Left(t.WhereCondition, Len(t.WhereCondition)-3)
End If
```

Comment: No AND or OR operator in the concatenation. This should fail. Use of AND operator won't work because doubt any record can meet the condition. And up to 70 OR operators might work but would be quite confusing in query design view, especially if other fields  have criteria.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for catching my concatenation mistake

Comment: Okay, but I don't really understand the TCondition object. Never seen this. Suppose OP has some custom class code?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming OP has a custom class

Comment: Also, probably should trim the trailing OR outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks again! I wrote a working solution and then scrapped it to use the OP's code. My hastiness cost me

Comment: If this method is used and want to have criteria under other fields as well, should include all these OR conditions within parens so the resulting criteria clause would be like: `this AND this AND this AND (this OR this OR this)`.

Comment: Reading through all this now. Apologies, I'm only at this during the day.

Comment: After a few hiccups of my own (if you noticed, I posted and deleted twice) this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Build function in a general module that returns a True or False. Call from query with expression like: `MC: MatchCounties([ID])` with filter criteria of `=True`.

Assuming the combobox lists county names exactly matching the yes/no field names, consider:

```
Function MatchCounties(intID As Integer) As Boolean
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim varItem As Variant
With Forms!formname.Counties
    If .ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Volunteer WHERE ID=" & intID)
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            If rs(.ItemData(varItem)) Then 'use the listbox value as field name and test for True
                MatchCounties = True
                Exit For 'only need to match 1 yes/no county field to retrieve record
            End If
        Next
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
End With
End Function
```

If no items selected in listbox, no records will return because the function will return False. If you want to allow no selection and still return records, then likely want the function to return True if .ItemsSelected.Count = 0. Adjust code with an Else.

Comment: Reading through this now. Apologies for the delay, I'm only at this during the day.

Comment: Brilliant as this is, it's unusable. Reason being that, in VBA, the WHERE condition is compiled, then, in VBA, the query is called. So this is never evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Why do you say it is not evaluated at runtime? I tested this. Built a report with the query calling function. Applied additional filter criteria with OpenReport method. Works perfect. You said you wanted a report. Did you test? How are you 'calling' query?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. I placed the function in a general module. I called it in the query. I placed a break point in the function. It should've triggered when the query called it. The query never called the function.

Comment: Well, can't explain that. It definitely works for me.

Comment: No worries, the other answer worked perfectly :) Thanks so much!